# how to use cpp dll plugin with class in unity

Tags: c#, c++, dll, unity-game-engine

I have some algorithm in cpp and trying to use them in unity.

after reading http://www.ericeastwood.com/blog/17/unity-and-dlls-c-managed-and-c-unmanaged, it's nice to have functions in cpp and use them in c sharp script in unity.

But what if I would like to have class things. I want my cpp class, construct reading resources and interface for update things everyframe. how to create and hold a class in unity c sharp?

my dummy sample code works like:

.h

```
     // TestCPPLibrary.h

 #ifdef TESTFUNCDLL_EXPORT
 #define TESTFUNCDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
 #else
 #define TESTFUNCDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
 #endif

 extern "C" {

     class myMath{
     private:
         int member;
     public:
         myMath();
         TESTFUNCDLL_API float multiple(float a, float b);
          TESTFUNCDLL_API float getMember();
     protected:
         virtual ~myMath();

     };

     TESTFUNCDLL_API float TestMultiply(float a, float b);
     TESTFUNCDLL_API float TestDivide(float a, float b);
     TESTFUNCDLL_API float get();
     TESTFUNCDLL_API myMath* _cdecl CreateMath();

     // Function Pointer Declaration of CreateMathObject() [Entry Point Function]
 typedef myMath* (*CREATE_MATH) ();

 }
```

.cpp

```
// TestCPPLibrary.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
 //

 #include "TestCPPLibrary.h"

 extern "C" {
     float TestMultiply(float a, float b)
     {
         return a * b;
     }

     float TestDivide(float a, float b)
     {
         if (b == 0) {
             return 0;
             //throw invalid_argument("b cannot be zero!");
         }

         return a / b;
     }

      float get()
     {
         return 5;
     }


      myMath* _cdecl CreateMath()
      {
          return new myMath();
      }

     float myMath::multiple(float a, float b)
     {
         if (b == 0) {
             return 0;
             //throw invalid_argument("b cannot be zero!");
         }

         return a / b;
     }

     float myMath::getMember()
     {
         return member;
     }

     myMath::myMath(){
         member = 6;
     }

     myMath::~myMath()
     {
     }

 }
```

c sharp code

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 using System.IO;

 public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

     [DllImport("TestCPPLibrary", EntryPoint="TestDivide")]
     public static extern float StraightFromDllTestDivide(float a, float b);

     [DllImport("TestCPPLibrary", EntryPoint="?getMember@myMath@@QEAAMXZ")]
     private static extern float getMember();


     private GameObject cube;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {
         cube = GameObject.Find ("Cube");

         float straightFromDllDivideResult = StraightFromDllTestDivide(20, 5);
         Debug.Log(straightFromDllDivideResult);

         float multipleResult = getMember();
         Debug.Log(multipleResult);
     }
     int i = 1;
     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {
         cube.transform.Rotate (Vector3.up * 50f * Time.deltaTime);
 //        Vector3 newVector = cube.transform.position;
 //        newVector.z = 15;
 //        cube.transform.position = newVector;

         cube.transform.position =new Vector3(0,0,i++ * Time.deltaTime);
     }
 }
```

I don't know how to new the class to an object and hold it in c sharp.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should first abstract your C code into C# ones using InterOp, test it without considering unity3D, try console app to simplify the process. Then put your C# dll (where your C# class resides) into the \plugins folder. This is easier to isolate and troubleshoot the problem.